# Blur Image in UIImageview Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiblureffect

I have an `UIImageView` which contains an image. Now i need to blur the image by 4% and change the darkness by 30% of the image, on certain button click, and Un blur it as well.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: how do I get rid of this effect again programmatically ?

Comment: There are many options. You can add custom blurr view to the imageview and remove it when u need.

Comment: You can use a single "UIVisualEffectView" object with a blur effect and place it over the UIImageView with same frame as UIImageView. Hide and Show it on button tap.